# Docker dns_search not resolving to docker-compose service

Tags: dns, docker-compose

My host machine is a Macbook and I am attempting to have docker auto-resolve all requested made to `*.docker`. Initially, I was using dinghy, which did the trick until (1) it no longer did the trick and (2) I learned that Docker for Mac should be able to do this.

In my docker-compose, that originally worked with dinghy, I had:

```
services:
  web:
    image: monin/magento:7.0-apache
    hostname: magento.docker
    ports:
      - 80
    volumes_from:
      - appdata
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=magento.docker
      - VIRTUAL_PORT=80
      - HTTPS_METHOD=noredirect
      - ENABLE_SENDMAIL=false
    links:
      - db
```

With the configuration above, I initially tried adding this to my docker daemon config and restarting:

```
"dns-search" : [
    "docker"
]
```

This didn't work, so I tried adding the following to my docker-compose:

```
services:
  web:
    ...
    dns: 8.8.8.8
    dns_search: docker
```

Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated.